# Passing Python variables through Nextflow channels

Tags: python, variable-assignment, nextflow

I have the following simplified task and get some errors when doing it.

I'm trying to get 4 letters from a string by Python and use that as a name of a new folder. My code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

params.string="abcdefg"

process PYTHON{
    input:
    val string
    
    output:
    val substring
    
    """
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    
    substring="$string"[0:4]
    """
}

process CREAT_FOLDER{
    input:
    val name
    
    """
    mkdir $name
    """
}

workflow{
    name = PYTHON(params.string)
    CREAT_FOLDER(name)
}
```

The error shows up.

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.1
Launching `python.nf` [shrivelled_kay] DSL2 - revision: 0e01fd9b95
executor >  local (1)
executor >  local (1)
[33/e827c9] process > PYTHON       [100%] 1 of 1, failed: 1 ✘
[-        ] process > CREAT_FOLDER -
ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'PYTHON'

Caused by:
  Missing value declared as output parameter: substring
```

The variable "substring" clearly couldn't pass through channels. **So how can I pass a Python variable into channels?**

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you need a globally scoped variable in order to declare it using the [`val`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#output-type-val) qualifier. The usual solution is to just define these in your [`script`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#script) block and then have Nextflow embed them in your Perl/Python/Bash script, for example:

```
params.string="abcdefg"
```

```
process PYTHON {

    debug true

    input:
    val string

    output:
    val substring

    script:
    substring = string.substring(0, 4)

    """
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    the_substring='${substring}'

    print(f'The substring: {the_substring}')
    """
}
```

```
process CREAT_FOLDER {

    debug true

    input:
    val name

    """
    mkdir -v "${name}"
    """
}
```

```
workflow {

    name = PYTHON(params.string)

    CREAT_FOLDER(name)
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.1
Launching `main.nf` [fervent_brazil] DSL2 - revision: 0676556654
executor >  local (2)
[3e/3f2501] process > PYTHON       [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[5b/fbcccb] process > CREAT_FOLDER [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
The substring: abcd

mkdir: created directory 'abcd'
```

---

For completeness, the alternative solution is to of course write the variable to a file and then read the value from it in your workflow block. For example:

```
params.string="abcdefg"
```

```
process PYTHON {

    input:
    val string

    output:
    path 'result.txt'

    """
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    substring='${string}'[0:4]

    with open('result.txt', 'w') as out:
        out.write(substring)
    """
}
```

```
process CREAT_FOLDER {

    debug true

    input:
    val name

    """
    mkdir -v "${name}"
    """
}
```

```
workflow {

    name = PYTHON(params.string).map { it.text }

    CREAT_FOLDER(name)
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.1
Launching `main.nf` [nauseous_yalow] DSL2 - revision: 64ed37cd94
executor >  local (2)
[c6/ad2f57] process > PYTHON       [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[ee/183f66] process > CREAT_FOLDER [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
mkdir: created directory 'abcd'
```